# Destructuring array of objects in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In es6, how can I simplify the following lines using destructuring?

```
const array0 = someArray[0].data;
const array1 = someArray[1].data;
const array2 = someArray[2].data;
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Whether using destructuring would actually be a simplification is debatable but this is how it can be done:

```
const [
  { data: array0 },
  { data: array1 },
  { data: array2 }
] = someArray
```

Live Example:

```js
const someArray = [
  { data: 1 },
  { data: 2 },
  { data: 3 }
];

const [
  { data: array0 },
  { data: array1 },
  { data: array2 }
] = someArray

console.log(array0, array1, array2);
```

What is happening is that you're first extracting each object from `someArray` then destructuring each object by extracting the `data` property and renaming it:

```
// these 2 destructuring steps
const [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ] = someArray // step 1
const { data: array0 } = obj1 // step 2
const { data: array1 } = obj2 // step 2
const { data: array2 } = obj3 // step 2

// written together give
const [
  { data: array0 },
  { data: array1 },
  { data: array2 }
] = someArray
```

Maybe combine destructuring with mapping for (potentially) more readable code:

```
const [array0, array1, array2] = someArray.map(item => item.data)
```

Live Example:

```js
const someArray = [
  { data: 1 },
  { data: 2 },
  { data: 3 }
];

const [array0, array1, array2] = someArray.map(item => item.data)

console.log(array0, array1, array2);
```

Comment: It's possible to use this to get an array with a specific property of an array of objects ? (length of array is random)

Answer (score 21):

I believe what you actually want is

```
const array = someArray.map(x => x.data)
```

If you really want three variables (*Hint: you shouldn't*), you can combine that `map`ping with destructuring:

```
const [array0, array1, array2] = someArray.map(x => x.data)
```

Comment: LOL, and here we all got caught up on the request to do it with destructuring.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do with this pure JS then follow this code snippet. It will help you.

```js
let myArray = [
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "subdata": [
            {
                "subid": "11",
                "name": "A"
            },
            {
                "subid": "12",
                "name": "B"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "subdata": [
            {
                "subid": "12",
                "name": "B"
            },
            {
                "subid": "33",
                "name": "E"
            }
        ]
    }
]


const array = myArray.map(x => x.subdata).flat(1)

const isExist = (key,value, a) => {
  return a.find(item => item[key] == value)
}

let a = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(!isExist('subid', curr.subid, acc)) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(a)
```

Comment: What question you've tried to solve? The current post is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myInfo = someArray.map((item) => {
const {itemval1, itemval2} = item;
return(
   //return data how you want it eg:
   <p>{itemval1}</p>
   <p>{itemval2}</p>)
})
```

This is how I did it in react, correct me if m wrong, I'm still new to this world

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel, I presume you were looking to destructure a nested Object in an array of Objects. Following @nem035 was able to extract the nested Object's property using his pattern.

What is happening is that you're first extracting each object from addresses array then destructuring each object by extracting its properties and renaming it including the nested Object:

```js
addresses = [
  {
    locality:"Sarjapura, Bangalore",
    coordinates:{latitude:"12.901160", longitude:"77.711680"}
  },
  {
    locality:"Vadakara, Kozhikode",
    coordinates:{latitude:"11.588980", longitude:"75.596450"}
  }
]
    
const [
  {locality:loc1, coordinates:{latitude:lat1, longitude:ltd1}}, 
  {locality:loc2, coordinates:{latitude:lat2, longitude:ltd2}}
] = addresses

console.log(`Latitude of Vadakara :: ${lat2}`)
```