# How to make a destructuring of this array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, destructuring

I'm trying to use destructuring on elements of my `subItems` array to get variables that refer directly to the `links` and `open` properties.
Specifically, I'm trying to use the following code, which fails as specified in the comments.

```
const [{links, open}] = subItems.map(({ items }) => {
  document.getElementById(items);
}); // Fails: returns nothing  

const {links, open} = subItems((items ) => {
  return items; 
}); // Fails: returns only the first `link` and `open`
      
// This is what the `subItems` array looks like:
export const subItems = [
  {
    links: [
      { title: 'ret', to: '#' },
      { title: 'def', to: '#' },
      { title: 'rev', to: '#' },
      { title: 'red', to: '#' },
      { title: 'im', to: '#' },
      { title: 'glossar', to: '#' }
    ],
    open: true
  },
  {
    links: [
      { title: 'recloud', to: '#' },
      { title: 'broker', to: '#' },
      { title: 'mercury', to: '#' },
      { title: 'investor', to: '#' }
    ],
    open: false
  }
];
```

P.S. I'm new to JS, sorry if I'm misunderstanding something trivial.

Comment: Which `links` and `open` do you want? There are two, one set at index 0 and another set at index 1. Or do you want an array of just those? Or...?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the `link` properties to one varaible? Something like this: [Destructure object properties inside array for all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069301) and [How to destructure an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022939)

Comment: You need to be more clearer on the output.
Please check if this helps you:
`subItems.map(({link, open})=>{

})`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question (or answer!), please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you're trying to do?:

```js
// Gets array (but you can get it any way you want, maybe by `import`)
const subItems = getSubItems();

// Loops through array (using `subItem` as the name for each array element)
for(subItem of subItems){

  // Destructures the current element in array (using `{...}` for objects)
  const {links, open} = subItem;

  // Collects links info (This is not needed -- just makes nicer printing)
  const linkString = links.reduce(
    (linkStr, link) => linkStr + `title:${link.title}, to:${link.to}; `,
    ""
  );

  // Does something with links and open (We could print `links` instead of linkString)
  console.log("links: ", linkString, "\nopen: ", open, "\n\n");
}
      
function getSubItems(){
  return [
    {
      links: [
        { title: 'ret', to: '#' },
        { title: 'def', to: '#' },
        { title: 'rev', to: '#' },
        { title: 'red', to: '#' },
        { title: 'im', to: '#' },
        { title: 'glossar', to: '#' }
      ],
      open: true
    },
    {
      links: [
        { title: 'recloud', to: '#' },
        { title: 'broker', to: '#' },
        { title: 'mercury', to: '#' },
        { title: 'investor', to: '#' }
      ],
      open: false
    }
  ];
}
```