# Filtering the data from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, destructuring

I'm trying object destructuring to filter the data with new array but, it gives me the same data.

I would like to filter out object properties in order to have in the new array objects with only the following 3 properties: **name**, **occupation**, **gender**

Trying to get any advice.

```
const employee = [
  {
    name: 'sam',
    occupation: 'designer',
    gender: 'M',
    email: 'sam.camp@around.com',
    salary: 40000,
    location: 'Canada'
  },
  {
    name: 'sara',
    occupation: 'developer',
    gender: 'M',
    email: 'sara.cap@around.com',
    salary: 30000,
    location: 'USA'
  },
];

function filterData(arr) {
  arr.map(( name, occupation, gender ) => ({ name, occupation, gender }));

  return arr
}

console.log(filterData(employee));
```

Comment: What are you wanting it to output? The `filterData` function takes in `arr` and then returns it.

Comment: `return arr.map(({ name, occupation, gender }) => ({ name, occupation, gender }))`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Destructuring array of objects in es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413544/destructuring-array-of-objects-in-es6)

Comment: Your edits don't make any sense and broke the question completely...

Comment: @Andreas Very elegant solution in 1 single line, it works - you Rock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like you want to "pluck" key-value pairs for each item.

```js
const employeeRecords = [{
  name: 'sam',
  occupation: 'designer',
  gender: 'M',
  email: 'sam.doe@somewhere.com',
  salary: 40000,
}, {
  name: 'sara',
  occupation: 'developer',
  gender: 'M',
  email: 'sara.eyre@somewhere.com',
  salary: 10000,
}];

const pluckData = (arr) =>
  arr.map(({ name, occupation, gender }) => ({ name, occupation, gender }));

console.log(pluckData(employeeRecords));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Alternatively, you could pass in an array of keys to pluck:

```js
const employeeRecords = [{
  name: 'sam',
  occupation: 'designer',
  gender: 'M',
  email: 'sam.doe@somewhere.com',
  salary: 40000,
}, {
  name: 'sara',
  occupation: 'developer',
  gender: 'M',
  email: 'sara.eyre@somewhere.com',
  salary: 10000,
}];

const pluckData = (arr, ...keys) =>
  arr.map(item =>
    keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: item[key] }), {}));

console.log(pluckData(employeeRecords, 'name', 'occupation', 'gender'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Like in the mentioned possible dupe

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE cannot infer the type of the array that is going to be passed to the function, so it'll be any type.

You can use JSDocs do define a type for the array though.

```
// @ts-check

// Typedefinitions

/**
 * @typedef EmployeeRecord
 *
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {string} occupation
 * @property {string} email
 * @property {string} gender
 * @property {number} salary
 */

/** @type {Array<EmployeeRecord>} */
const employeeRecords = [
  {
    name: "sam",
    occupation: "designer",
    gender: "M",
    email: "sam.doe@somewhere.com",
    salary: 40000,
  },
  {
    name: "sara",
    occupation: "developer",
    gender: "M",
    email: "sara.eyre@somewhere.com",
    salary: 10000,
  },
];

/**
 *
 * @param {Array<EmployeeRecord>} arr Array of employee records
 * @returns
 */
function filterData(arr) {
  const [{ name, occupation, gender }] = arr;

  return arr;
}

console.log(filterData(employeeRecords));
```

Comment: What has this to do with an IDE or JSDoc? o.O

Comment: Javascript is a dinamically typed language, so it only makes sense if the IDE is trying to infer the types (which in that case wasn't possible). The original question was way different too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

There might be a more elegant way, but it works.

```js
const employee = [
  {
    name: 'sam',
    occupation: 'designer',
    gender: 'M',
    email: 'sam.camp@around.com',
    salary: 40000,
    location: 'Canada'
  },
  {
    name: 'sara',
    occupation: 'developer',
    gender: 'M',
    email: 'sara.cap@around.com',
    salary: 30000,
    location: 'USA'
  },
];

function filterData(arr) {
  let arrFiltered = arr.map(item => {
    let container = {};
    container.name = item.name;
    container.occupation = item.occupation;
    container.gender = item.gender;
    return container
  })
  return arrFiltered
};

console.log(filterData(employee));
```

**Output**:

```
[
  {
    name: 'sam',
    occupation: 'designer',
    gender: 'M'
  },
  {
    name: 'sara',
    occupation: 'developer',
    gender: 'M'
  }
]
```

By the way: I corrected property values for `location:` into strings

`location: canada` to `location: "Canada"` and  `location: USA` to `location: "USA"`

Also, there was an issue with a variable in your code:

I changed `console.log(filterData(employeeRecords))` to `console.log(filterData(employee))`

I hope I understood correctly your question and that this helps.

I just saw **VERY elegant** solution from @Andreas from comments above:
(makes me look stupid, ha ha ha)

```
function filterData(arr) {
  return arr.map(({ name, occupation, gender }) => ({ name, occupation, gender }))
};
```

Congrats to @Andreas - I tested it and it works like a charm :-)